# Hibernate native SQL query type mapping from java.sql.Date to java.time.LocalDate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am doing a SELECT query, using a Hibernate native query, like below:

```java
public List<SomeDTO> findDTOs() {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" SELECT id as id, localDateColumn as date, ");

    sql.append(" FROM t");
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
    query.unwrap(SQLQuery.class)
        .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
        .addScalar("localDateColumn", DateType.INSTANCE)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SomeDTO.class));
    return query.getResultList();
  }
```

I tried using `StandardBasicTypes.DATE` or `DateType.INSTANCE` which does not work. I know that it works fine to map `java.sql.Types#DATE` and `java.util.Date`.

I would like to know how would I map `java.sql.Types#DATE` to `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not using `Entity` for return data type. `AttributeConverter` is not useful in this case.
I resolved this by manually converting the `java.util.Date` into `java.time.LocalDate` in the setter of the field.

Setter will look like this:

```java
public void setLocalDateColumn(java.util.Date value){
    // convert into LocalDate
    // set
}
```

If you get `UnsupportedOperationException` while converting. You might still getting `java.sql.Date` here wrapped in `java.util.Date`. Do it like:
`Instant.ofEpochMilli(value.getTime()).atZone(DefaultZoneId).toLocalDate();`

Answer (score 2):

There are many things which are wrong with your approach.

### Risking SQL Injection attacks

The way you are building the SQL using String concatenation is very risky and can expose your application to [SQL injection attacks](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/).

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append(" SELECT id as id, localDateColumn as date, ");

sql.append(" FROM t");
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
```

More, it's not even correct since you append a `,` prior to the `FROM` clause. You need to use [Criteria API](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-api-bulk-update-delete/) if you want to build queries dynamically.

### Aliases are not used properly

You set the `localDateColumn` column to the `date` alias like this:

```
sql.append(" SELECT id as id, localDateColumn as date, ");
```

But then you use the `localDateColumn` when setting the Hibernate Type using `addScalar`:

```
.addScalar("localDateColumn", DateType.INSTANCE)
```

Now, according to your question title, if the `localDateColumn` is a MySQL `DATE` column type, and you want to map it to a `LocalDate` Java Object, you should do it like this:

```
.addScalar("date", LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: I just used dummy SQLs to simply explain the approach, please ignore syntax or aliases, question is about mapping the date type. The suggested solution return `java.util.Date` but I wanted it to convert into `java.time.LocalDate`. Please see my answer.

Comment: If you use `.addScalar("date", LocalDateType.INSTANCE)`, you should get that.

Comment: And you should definitely read my answer carefully because you have even bigger problems in your code than what you initially posted the question for.